# Binding an Image source to TextBox.Text

Tags: wpf, image

I am trying to bind the Text of a TextBox named 'txtImage' to an image using the following code with no results:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ElementName=txtImage, Path=Text}" />
```

What would the right approach be?

Comment: Are you getting binding errors in the output when running from Visual Studio? I'd doubt that you can use a String as an ImageSource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source of an Image requires a BitmapImage, thus try using a Value Converter to convert the string to an Image:

```
public sealed class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            return new BitmapImage(new Uri((string)value));
        }
        catch 
        {
            return new BitmapImage();
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
                              object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

```
<Image>
    <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding ElementName=txtImage, Path=Text, Converter=...}" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

*Reference: [Image UriSource and Data Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586/wpf-image-urisource-and-data-binding)*

Comment: In order for this to work, would the converter have to be decared in procedural code?

Comment: The converter should be declared in the Resources section (in xaml).  For example, in Window.Resources

Comment: how do I declare the converter for this particular case in resources?