# xaml image not showing .source

Tags: wpf, image, xaml

I am new to xaml and wpf in general.
I am trying to make an image appear in a user control this is the code I use:

```
   BitmapImage captchaSource = new BitmapImage();
                        captchaSource.BeginInit();
                        captchaSource.UriSource = new Uri(_captchaData.ImgUrl);
                        captchaSource.EndInit();
                        captchaImg.Source = captchaSource;
```

this is the ui code:

```
<Image Height="105" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,38,0,0" Name="captchaImg" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="276" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
```

But nothing happens. No image appears. This is the url in _captchaData.ImgUrl http://www.google.ro/images/srpr/logo3w.png

Does anyone have any idea why this is?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF Image UriSource and Data Binding using http:\\ URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148163/wpf-image-urisource-and-data-binding-using-http-url)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148163/wpf-image-urisource-and-data-binding-using-http-url):

> "WebURL can't be provided as a source to UriSource property of
>   BitmapImage. If it is weburl you need to download that image locally
>   and bind that path to UriSource."