# Image Renders in Win8/Win10 but not Win7

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-7

I have the following XAML in my document:

```
<Border HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        Height="100" Width="100"
        BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2">
    <Image x:Name="image"
           Source="http://myinternalserver/mywebservice/getimage.aspx?id=1234&amp;ContentType=Image" />
</Border>
```

The image shows up fine in Win10 and Win8, but in Win7 all I get is a red border with a transparent background and no image inside.  When I use a static URL, like to the google logo, it renders in all versions.

Anyone have any idea how I can make the image render in Windows 7?

Comment: What is the image type? Does that type is supported natively by Windows 7?

Comment: Yes, it's a PNG, sometimes a JPG.  Nothing exotic.

Comment: Can you access that link from the browser? it doesnt seem to me like a xaml/c# issue. more like windows setup issue...

Comment: Yep, it opens in the browser just fine on both systems.

Comment: maybe a server issue, headers, etc. Without a reproducing sample, it's hard to tell.

Comment: Is there any error message in your output window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3148290/4625433) WebUrl can't be specified as the Source of a BitmapImage. I recommend to you to make a helper class instead of doing so in the code-behind of the view. Also I would freeze the created image for performance.

Answer (score 2):

Try to check possible exception by subscribing on the `Image.ImageFailed` event from the code-behind file:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    image.ImageFailed += ImageFailed;
}

private void ImageFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ErrorException);
}
```