# Button/Image Switch resource using click, MouseEnter and MouseLeave

Tags: wpf, image, button, resources, mouseenter

I'm trying to change an image using events like Click, MouseEnter and MouseLeave. In first place I tried to do it with Buttons in order to have "Click" event too, but I don't know how to remove that lightblue background that appears by default when I put the mouse over the button with a png background.

After this, I tried to use , setting the resource image.png in its Source.

The main problem is that I don't know what to do in code-behind to change between Image Resources in order to change the Source of the  control.

I want to know too if I can use a "Click Event" with an  control

Update1:

Ok, I tried it by using Binding
For now I think its solved, but I have another problem.
I don't know exactly how to remove that "border". I tried to put the borderbrush property of the buttons to 0, but it seems to be another property or another control.

[UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5krt.png)

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a code sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can put an image as the **content of a button,** and add an Click event to that Button. This way, an event gets called when you press the button.

```
        <Button Margin="0,10" Name="mainButton" Click="mainButton_Click">
            <Button.Content>
                <Image Source="C:/reference-to-image" Height="30"/>
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
```

In the background you can than change the Picture.

This question shows how to do that in the background.

[WPF Image UriSource and Data Binding using http:\\ URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148163/wpf-image-urisource-and-data-binding-using-http-url)

PS. If you want to change the behavior of controls on certain events things like pressing the left mouse button on it, you have to overwrite the **event triggers** using

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                          ...
```

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**

You can set the `BorderThickness` to 0 and than set the Value of the `Padding` Property to 0. The Button Control has a **predefined padding value**, which makes it look like it has a border. 
Padding is the **space inside the control and the content** e.g the space between the button and the picture

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Click="Button_Click"  Padding="0" BorderThickness="0">
            <Image Source="link-to-pic" Height="100"/>
        </Button>
        <Button Click="Button_Click"   Padding="0"  BorderThickness="0">
            <Image Source="link-to-pic" Height="100"/>
        </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: If this helps you, make sure to upvote my answer and mark it as correct. Thank you