# using XAML to bind to a System.Drawing.Image into a System.Windows.Image control

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, binding

I'm binding a ListView to a list of objects, like so;

```
<ListView 
    ItemsSource="{ Binding Path=. }"
    ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource EventTemplate}">
```

I'm binding to an object which declares two properties;

```
string DisplayName { get; }
System.Drawing.Image Image { get; set; }
```

I want to populate a `DataTemplate` but I can't figure out how; if I do this in my template;

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image Source="{ Binding Path=Image }" />
    <TextBlock Text="{ Binding Path=DisplayName }" />
</StackPanel>
```

The text appears but the image does not. What am I doing wrong? The debug output shows

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 1 : Cannot create default converter
to perform 'one-way' conversions between types
'System.Drawing.Image' and 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource'.
Consider using Converter property of Binding.
BindingExpression:Path=Image; DataItem='RealElement'
(HashCode=54308798); target element is 'Image' (Name='');
target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource')
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Found a way I'm happy with. Using [Reed Copsey's pointer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/833ca60f-6a11-4836-bb2b-ef779dfe3ff0/) and [this tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-binding-converters) I've wrapped the code as a `IValueConverter`.

Here's the converter from `System.Drawing.Image` to `System.Windows.Media.ImageSource`;

```
using System;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace System.Windows.Media
{
    /// <summary>
    /// One-way converter from System.Drawing.Image to System.Windows.Media.ImageSource
    /// </summary>
    [ValueConversion(typeof(System.Drawing.Image), typeof(System.Windows.Media.ImageSource))]
    public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
            object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            // empty images are empty...
            if (value == null) { return null; }

            var image = (System.Drawing.Image)value;
            // Winforms Image we want to get the WPF Image from...
            var bitmap = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
            bitmap.BeginInit();
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            // Save to a memory stream...
            image.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            // Rewind the stream...
            memoryStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
            bitmap.StreamSource = memoryStream;
            bitmap.EndInit();
            return bitmap;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
            object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you need to bring the image converter into XAML as a resource;

```
xmlns:med="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Media"
...

<ListView.Resources>
    <med:ImageConverter x:Key="imageConverter" />
</ListView.Resources>
```

Then you can use it in XAML to bind directly to the Image, using the new converter;

```
<Image Source="{ Binding Path=Image, Converter={StaticResource imageConverter} }" />
```

Comment: I have a question about memory usage: does this conversion take place only once or each time the Image is to shown in the visible part of i.e. ListBox ??

Comment: Can't really say -- the conversion is done every time it's needed by WPF -- so I think it's just an internal implementation detail. I don't think there'd be any reason for it to be converted over and over, but it might be worth sticking in a counter and seeing...

Comment: `memoryStream` is never closed or disposed, is that a concern here? I have some very similar code, that might have even come from this question, but it's uglier.

Comment: For the future readers, do remember to dispose the previous `Image` instance in the property setter. This is in response to @Maslow's comment.

Answer (score 5):

You can't bind that directly - you need to have some type of converter that will convert from a GDI Image to a WPF Image.

Here is [one approach](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/833ca60f-6a11-4836-bb2b-ef779dfe3ff0/) - it uses a memory stream to pull the data from the GDI image and create a BitmapSource object.

Comment: Hi -- thanks for the pointer. I'm half-way through reading your "Better User and Developer Experiences – From Windows Forms to WPF with MVVM" articles at the moment; great stuff. Anyway, that gave me enough to get to the answer; I've posted it alongside.

Comment: @Steve: Glad to hear you're liking the series ;)

Comment: It's been really helpful. The WPF model is very different from windows forms, and your essays are helping unlock it in my brain.

Comment: The `memoryStream` in that example is never disposed, and not in a using or closed. is this a problem?