# How to set image in Image control of WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I am getting an image in the format System.Drawing.Image from a 3rd party dll at runtime. This image is to be set to a WPF Image control on the UI. How to achieve this.

Note that the image is in memory and not stored on disk.

Please help.

Comment: There are a lot of similar questions around. Eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427034/using-xaml-to-bind-to-a-system-drawing-image-into-a-system-windows-image-control

Comment: Did you try System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(MemoryStream)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the library's name is `TestLibrary` and the path toof the image is `/Images/Image1.png`. You can set Image's Source property like below.

```
<Image Source="/TestLibrary;Component/Images/Image1.png"/>
```

You can visit [Pack URIs in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx) for further reference.

Comment: Have you read a question? "Note that the image is in memory and not stored on disk".