# how Image Binding Dynamically WPF?

Tags: c#, data-binding, wpf-controls

i need to bind an image on run time in code behind thing is it's for WPF user control how can i do it? think i'm totally new to WPF and please explain how to do it appreciate your reply.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily create binding in code : [How to: Create a Binding in Codee](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742863.aspx)

But it can be problematic form Image control, because Source property requires ImageSource type, but in XAML, you usualy specify URI itself and XAML will convert it apropriately.
See more here : [WPF Image UriSource and Data Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586/wpf-image-urisource-and-data-binding)

If you dont understand something, please edit your question.