# How set default image?

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid, converters

DataGrid:

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Image Tag="{Binding photo}" MinWidth="50"  Source="{Binding photo, Converter={StaticResource ConvertNullImageKey}}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Converter if value not uri return iamge from ImageResource.noimage. But this bitmap...How return URI on bitmap?

```
public class ConvertNullImage : IValueConverter
        {
            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                try
                {
                    Uri uri = new Uri(value.ToString(), UriKind.Relative);
                    return uri;
                }
                catch { return new Uri(ImageResource.noimage); }
            }

            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                                      CultureInfo culture)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Image.Source` property is not of type `Uri`, it is of type `ImageSource`, see MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source%28VS.95%29.aspx

When you set an `Image.Source` in XAML, the XAML parser is cunningly converting your URI into an `ImageSource`.

So - you need to create a `BitmapImage` in your value converter. See this related question:

[Image UriSource and Data Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586/wpf-image-urisource-and-data-binding)

Answer (score 0):

The `Source` property of the `Image` expects an `ImageSource`, and not a URI. This works in xaml thanks to a [TypeConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645047%28VS.95%29.aspx). You can create a BitmapImage from the path and return that as shown [here](http://vivekdalvi.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/binding-to-image-source/).

If I understand correctly, the second part of the problem is that you want to bind (as a default value) to an image from a Resource file. If that's so, here's an [article on how to do that on MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jitghosh/archive/2008/10/25/binding-an-embedded-image-using-a-value-converter.aspx)

hope this helps :)