# ListBox Not showing image

Tags: silverlight, image, xaml, windows-phone-7, binding

I have a list box XAML of which looks like this

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}">
    <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="ComplaintslistBox" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Width="400" BorderThickness="1">
                    <Button.Content>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Image Source="{Binding Type}" Width="30" Height="30"></Image>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Head}" Width="300"></TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button.Content>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

now the problem is it is binding "Head" but not binding the "Type"

Type variable contains path to the image which is to be shown....

class looks like this

```
public class Complaints
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Head { get; set; }
    //public string Desc { get; set; }
    public string lat { get; set; }
    public string lon { get; set; }
    public string wardNo { get; set; }
    public string wardName { get; set; }
    public string creator { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string catId { get; set; }
    public string subCatId { get; set; }
    public int commentCount { get; set; }
    public int solutionCount { get; set; }
    public int affectedCount { get; set; }

    public Complaints() { }

    public Complaints(Complaints complaints)
    {
        this.Id = complaints.Id;
        this.Head = complaints.Head;
        //this.Desc = complaints.Desc;

        switch (complaints.Type)
        {
            case "Reported":
                this.Type = "icons/icon_red.png";
                break;
            case "Reopened":
                this.Type = "icons/icon_black.png";
                break;
            case "Resolved":
                this.Type = "icons/icon_green.png";
                break;
            default:
                this.Type = "icons/icon_blue.png";
                break;
        }

        this.wardNo = complaints.wardNo;
        this.wardName = complaints.wardName;

        this.lat = complaints.lat;
        this.lon = complaints.lon;

        this.catId = complaints.catId;
        this.subCatId = complaints.subCatId;

        this.url = complaints.url;
        this.creator = complaints.creator;

        this.affectedCount = complaints.affectedCount;
        this.commentCount = complaints.commentCount;
        this.solutionCount = complaints.solutionCount;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: It is binding but it is not getting displayed. even if we hard core the source

Comment: i followed this tutorial - 

http://3water.wordpress.com/2010/07/25/listbox-on-wp7/

Answer (score 1):

Binding to an `ImageSource` might be easier than binding to a `string`.

You'll need something like this:

```
var ISC = new System.Windows.Media.ImageSourceConverter();

this.Type = (ImageSource)ISC.ConvertFromString(ImagePath);
```

where Type is:

```
public ImageSource Type { get; set; }
```

rather than `string`.

Comment: The following question covers most of image binding scenarios: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586/wpf-image-urisource-and-data-binding

Comment: Actually you should be able to bind to strings just fine, so what you are saying is kind of wrong.

Comment: @Sirwani - Are these images resources in the project? If so see [H.B.'s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8474372/59303).

Comment: Images are resources in build action but not acting like resources :(

Answer (score 0):

The question is where those images are located, if those are resources in the assembly you need to qualify the path using [Pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx) syntax, in fact it can never hurt to fully qualify the path. So if you use resources it should be something like:

```
"pack://application:,,,/icons/icon_red.png"
```