# Async loading of images

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, binding, asynchronous, windows-phone

I want to use best way to show images in my PanoramaPage. I download one page and shows it´s information a then I want to async load another page with images. So I am using  `HttpWebRequest` and I get response. Everything is okay and hope this is best way for these. So I create my GaleryViewModel and for all images at page I add url to my class.
And there is a problem. I can´t see images in view. This i my view:

```xml
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Images}" x:Name="listImages" Height="652" Canvas.Top="80">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17">
               <Image Height="100" Width="100" Margin="12,0,9,0" >
                   <Image.Source>
                       <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding ImgURL}" CreateOptions="BackgroundCreation"/>
                   </Image.Source>
               </Image>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
           </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This is content of my WebResponse event handler:

```cs
MovieExt movie = this.DataContext as MovieExt;

HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(response);

var photos = from ti in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
             where ti.Attributes["class"] != null && ti.Attributes["class"].Value == "photo"
             select ti;
Regex rgx = new Regex("http://[0-9a-zA-Z_./]+");

foreach (var photo in photos)
{
    GaleryViewModel fotka = new GaleryViewModel();
    string style = photo.Attributes["style"].Value;

    MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(style);
    if (matches.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (Match match in matches)
            fotka.ImgURL = match.Value;
    }
    fotka.LineOne = "Test";
    movie.Images.Add(fotka);
}
this.DataContext = movie;
this.listImages.ItemsSource = movie.Images;
```

and for all GaleryViewModel and MovieExt:

```cs
    public class GaleryViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
      private string _imgUrl;
      public string ImgURL
      {
        get
        {
            return _imgUrl;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _imgUrl)
            {
                _imgUrl = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ImgURL");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _lineOne;
    public string LineOne
    {
        get
        {
            return _lineOne;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _lineOne)
            {
                _lineOne = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("LineOne");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (null != handler)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

public class MovieExt
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
 ...
    public List<GaleryViewModel> Images { get; set; }
 ...
 }
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but I think that is something with binding. Thanks for help

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint in `GaleryViewModel.ImgURL.get` and seeing if that is hit? If not that would indicate a binding problem.

Comment: I tried it and I have hit first set a then multiple times get (for all images which I add) and last get for itemssource.

Comment: What is this movie in movie.Images.Add?
Is it observableCollection?
Also instead of using List<> you should use ObservableCollection<>
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42536/List-vs-ObservableCollection-vs-INotifyPropertyCha

Comment: I change List to ObservableCollection and it really helps. Thanks very much but I dont know how to add you reputation for this when its in comment.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this it looks like you haven't notified that the `MovieExt.Images` property has changed. Without doing this your `ListBox` won't update its `Items`. To do this `MovieExt` will also need to support `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: I added INotifyPropertyChanged and not help it :/

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert `Uri` to `BitmapImage`, because `BitmapImage UriSource` is a stream. Please take a look at this: [Image UriSource and Data Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586/wpf-image-urisource-and-data-binding)

Answer (score 0):

Replace loading method (just for test) to:

```cs
MovieExt movie = new MovieExt();
movie.Images = new List<GaleryViewModel>();
GaleryViewModel fotka1 = new GaleryViewModel();
fotka1.LineOne = "line1";
fotka1.ImgURL = "http://proservice.kiev.ua/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/apple-logo.jpg";
GaleryViewModel fotka2 = new GaleryViewModel();
fotka2.LineOne = "line2";
fotka2.ImgURL = "http://www.mykhailenko.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/apple-logo-history-2.png";
movie.Images.Add(fotka1);
movie.Images.Add(fotka2);
listImages.ItemsSource = movie.Images;
```

and it works

I guess the problem is in this line:

```cs
if (matches.Count > 0)
```

You have no matches, so your `Url` is empty

*Can you provide us data your service return to debug code in your context?*

Also, why you need loop for this assignment?

```cs
foreach (Match match in matches)
    fotka.ImgURL = match.Value;
```