# C# Windows Phone: Is it possible to fill LongListSelector with images?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, longlistselector

I fill a LongListSelector with names of products and i would like to put images of products too in my LongListSelector. I get my datas from my webserver using webclient method. To get an image i only know i should use something like this:

```
pic.Source = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri("http://srvname.com/images/greenpasta.jpg"));
```

But i don't know how to show images on long list selector.

Comment: What does your xaml look like? You probably need to use a `ValueCoverter` I recommend you look at this similar post to get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586/image-urisource-and-data-binding

Comment: (sorry for the code in comment i have a new stack account i can t post a answer)Thanks to help me. My xaml looks like this:

> <DataTemplate>
>     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
>         <Image Source="{Binding Img}" Height="100" Stretch="Fill"/>
>         <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
>             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
>         </StackPanel>
>     </StackPanel>  </DataTemplate>

Comment: @user3627729 You can edit your question to add more code or infomation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep the URL of the image as an attribute to your product, not the image source itself. So you can have something like

```
    myProduct.uri = new Uri("http://srvname.com/images/greenpasta.jpg")
```

And in xaml:

```
    <DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinition>
      <ColumnDefinition Witdh="100" \>
      <ColumnDefinition Witdh="Auto" \>
      <ColumnDefinition Witdh="*" \>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinition>
      <Image Source="{Binding uri}" Height="100" Stretch="Fill"/> >           
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" /> >
    </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Just as a suggestion, by replacing the stackpanel to a grid, you can already reserve space for your image (100 pixels), which is downloaded async. Otherwise, when the image will apear on the screen, it will move all the other content.