# How can I simply load an image file and show it in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I have this xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="TestWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
        <Image Width="100" Height="100" Source="{Binding theImage}"/>
</Window>
```

And this code behind:

```
namespace TestWPF
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        BitmapImage theImage = new BitmapImage();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            theImage.BeginInit();
            theImage.UriSource = new Uri("dice.png", UriKind.Relative);
            theImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            theImage.EndInit();
            OnPropertyChanged("theImage");
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Why is the image not showing up? I understand my code may be completely backwards. I'm just having trouble wrapping my head around the WPF way. Where things like this in Qt are dead simple, I can't seem to find anything relevant for this.

Comment: `BitmapImage theImage = new BitmapImage();` set it to `pubic` and add a  Getter/Setter `{get; set;}`

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586/image-urisource-and-data-binding

Comment: Do you want to use DataBinding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BitmapImage theImage should be a property, binding can't be used with fields.

```
    public BitmapImage theImage {get; set;}

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = this;

        theImage = new BitmapImage();
        theImage.BeginInit();
        theImage.UriSource = new Uri("dice.png", UriKind.Relative);
        theImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        theImage.EndInit();
        OnPropertyChanged("theImage");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your Image a name

```
<Image x:Name="MyImage" Width="100" Height="100"/>
```

and assign the BitmapImage to the source property in the ctor of your mainwindow

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        theImage.BeginInit();
        theImage.UriSource = new Uri("dice.png", UriKind.Relative);
        theImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        theImage.EndInit();
        MyImage.Source = theImage;
    }
```

Comment: This works, as does setting the `DataContext` explicitly to (in this case) `this`, as in @Anton's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended pattern for WPF applications is `MVVM`, where you have a view model class that declares the source properties of the bindings in the view (and implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface to notify about property value changes):

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ImageSource theImage;

    public ImageSource TheImage
    {
        get { return theImage; }
        set
        {
            theImage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

In your view you would assign the `DataContext` property to an instance of the view model. If you don't set the DataContext, the source objects of the bindings would have to be set explicitly.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var vm = new ViewModel();
    DataContext = vm;

    vm.TheImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("dice.png", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

The binding in your XAML would look like this:

```
<Image ... Source="{Binding TheImage}"/>
```

Comment: Right, and for simplicity's sake, the `MainWindow` class is also my `ViewModel`. Nothing prevents that from working.

Comment: Of course not, but separating view and view model makes things easier to understand. Anyway, your approach would require `DataContext = this;` in the MainWindow constructor, and `theImage` being a public property instead of a field.

Comment: Right. So that, and not an explanation of MVVM, is the answer to my question. Question then becomes why `DataContext` is not set to a sane default in the first place.

Comment: Because `this`is not a "sane default" in many cases, e.g. UserControls.